# Get extra information from callback validation Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get some extra information from a callback inside the controller.

The controler asks for validation with this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('csvfile', 'Upload CSV', 'callback_csv_upload');
```

The validation callback is supposed to manage all about the file upload.
Now, what I want to do is use that upload information further into the controller:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('csvfile', 'Upload CSV', 'callback_csv_upload');

do something with --- $this->lists->csvinfo;
```

**// callback inside controller**

```
function csv_upload(){
      if($_FILES['csvfile']['size'] != 0){
        $upload_dir = './uploads/';
        if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
             mkdir($upload_dir);
        }   
        $config['upload_path']   = $upload_dir;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv|txt';
        $config['file_name']     = 'csv_'.substr(md5(rand()),0,7);

        $config['overwrite']     = false;
        $config['max_size']  = '5120';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('csvfile')){
            $this->form_validation->set_message('csv_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
            return false;
        }   
        else{
             $this->load->model('lists');
            $this->lists->set_csvinfo($this->upload->data());
            return true;
        }   
    }   
    else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('csv_upload', "No csv file selected");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
Class Lists extends CI_Model
{
    public $csvinfo = 'xx';     

    function set_csvinfo($info){

        $this->csvinfo = $info;

    }

}
```

Seems like whatever I do inside that callback doesn't affect the Model variable - in prints out the default 'xx' value.
If I try to call de set_csvinfo() in the controller, the variable is changing, but never when called inside the callback function.

Comment: try to remove the single quotes here `$config['max_size'] = 5120`;

Comment: Thank you. I will do that but that's not the problem here.
The file gets uploaded just fine only that I cannot use the uploaded file info outside the callback function.

Comment: try to return your function `retrun $this->lists->set_csvinfo($this->upload->data());` instead of `return true;`

Comment: Still no change. 
Is there anyway I could you the return result? Using $info = $this->lists->csvinfo; doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh, I think your `$csvinfo` variable should be a type of array so it need to be `$csvinfo = []` since the `$this->upload->data()` returns an array

Comment: change ```public $csvinfo = 'xx';```   to ```public $csvinfo = array();```

Comment: I was trying to get the value before $this->form_validation->run();

Comment: @valiD Kindly if your problem is solved now post your answer so the community will know how did you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$csvinfo` must be a type of array since the `$this->upload->data()` returns an **array**

```
Class Lists extends CI_Model
{
    public $csvinfo = [];      

    function set_csvinfo($info){

        $this->csvinfo = $info;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My validation callback function din not trigger unless calling  $this->form_validation->run();

```
function csv_upload(){
.......
$this->lists->csvinfo = 'upload info';
..........
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules('csvfile', 'Upload CSV', 'callback_csv_upload');

$this->form_validation->run();
do something with --- $this->lists->csvinfo;
```